# Is there an Application/add-on that can find a Dead locks in my code in advance?

Tags: .net

Besides the obvious best practice of avoiding Dead-locks is there something that check it automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/03/23/locking

Comment: thanks Adam, I would like to avoid dead locks and not to release the locks after it already happened.

Comment: yes, we'd all like to avoid deadlocks :-) however this will allow you to track them down if they happen, which is a step on from nothing